# merge two rows into one in seperate columns

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks roughly like this

```
Job     Description           Value
1234    Sunday Collection      325
1234    Rush Charge            82
```

I need it to be

```
Job     Description1           Value1      Description2           Value2
1234    Sunday Collection      325         Rush Charge            82
```

Can this be done in a View or is there a way through simple sql query

Comment: `pivot` is what you are looking for

Comment: Do a self (outer) join,

Comment: The company I work for wont allow access to sql so I am doing this on a free sql type package  (flyspeed) it wont let me use pivot

Comment: Would there be just two rows with job like you specified in your example.

Comment: What kind of database / version? And can there be only 2 descriptions, ore more?

Comment: Yes there is a possibility of 2 rows most jobs will just have one row but the description may change from a list of 16

Comment: "...won't allow access to sql..." >> And they've asked you to write SQL against their database? That's about the same as letting someone borrow your car but not giving them keys. First, I'd tell them you can't do what they ask without better access. Also, are you sure this is FlySpeed preventing you from a PIVOT and not your database? What flavor and what version of SQL are you accessing?